# Dlib file faliure

Tags: python, dlib

Using cached dlib-19.23.1.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [59 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
package init file 'tools\python\dlib_*init*_.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
-A x64'
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):

```
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  
  
    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
 
 
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 
 
 
 
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\setup.py", line 134, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension       
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Ashutosh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9706xhel\\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Ashutosh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9706xhel\\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\ashutosh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Ashutosh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9706xhel\\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [61 lines of output]
running install
running build
running build_py
package init file 'tools\python\dlib_*init*_.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
-A x64'
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):

```
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 
 
    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
 
 
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 
 
 
 
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
      return orig.install.run(self)
    File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
      self.run_command('build')
```

tutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\setup.py", line 134, in run
self.build_extension(ext)
File "C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
File "c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\tools\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\ashutosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9706xhel\dlib_e88c79f59c944138ae00b54ff772a057\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: What exactly did you do to get to this point?  Are you trying to install dlib from source?  Through `pip`?  Please provide more - this is not enough for us to diagnose your error. Please see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: i tried using command pip install dlib .                                                                                  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

Comment: If you are using Windows to install `dlib`, you'll need to install Visual Studio: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).